# pymacs: General question and Installation problem

Tags: python, emacs, rope, pymacs

I am trying to setup emacs for python development.

From what I read, it is recommended to use python-mode.el rather than the default python.el from Emacs 22.3. So I embark on the new adventure.

From what I understand, python-mode has the several dependencies, so I need to install rope, ropemode and ropemacs. Then on top of that I need to install pymacs.

**Q: is it correct?**

This is my new .emacs now:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(tab-width 4))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(setq emacs-config-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(setq base-lisp-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")
(setq site-lisp-path (concat emacs-config-path "/site-lisp"))
(defun add-path (p)
  (add-to-list 'load-path (concat base-lisp-path p)))

(add-path "") 
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")

(require 'psvn)

;; python-mode
;;
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.py$" . python-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq interpreter-mode-alist (cons '("python" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist))
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python editing mode." t)


(setq pymacs-load-path '(   "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/rope"
                            "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemode"
                            "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemacs"))


(setq interpreter-mode-alist
      (cons '("python" . python-mode)
        interpreter-mode-alist)
      python-mode-hook
      '(lambda () (progn
            (set-variable 'py-indent-offset 4)
            (set-variable 'py-smart-indentation nil)
            (set-variable 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
            ;;(highlight-beyond-fill-column)
                    (define-key python-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)
            (pabbrev-mode)
            (abbrev-mode)
     )
      )
)


;; pymacs
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)

;; Search local path for emacs rope
;;

;; enable pymacs
;; 
(require 'pymacs)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
```

Now, when i start emacs, I got this error message:

```
("C:\\opt\\emacs-22.3\\bin\\emacs.exe")
Loading encoded-kb...done
Loading regexp-opt...done
Loading easy-mmode...done
Loading wid-edit...done
Loading edmacro...done
Loading derived...done
Loading advice...done
Loading cl-macs...done
Loading byte-opt...done


An error has occurred while loading `c:/opt/cygwin/home/akong/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, pymacs

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a. [2 times]
```

To make it slightly more complicated:

For work reason I have to use python 2.4, but I have python 2.6 installed on my PC. But obviously rope does not like 2.4 so I did not run setup.py. I untar/unzip these packages and put these files under ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp. By default if python is invoked in command prompt, it is the python 2.4 executable.

**Q: How can I successfully load 'pymacs'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I missed these two:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Pymacs-0.23")
```

Obviously I need to load the pymac script.

And I have set the env var PYMACS_PYTHON to python 2.6 because I am using python 2.4 as default python interpreter, for work reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used pymacs so far, but one thing which catches my eye when I look at your `.emacs` is that you apparently didn't add the pymacs directory to the *emacs* `load-path` but only to the `pymacs` one:

```
(setq pymacs-load-path '( "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/rope"
                          "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemode"
                          "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemacs"))
```

You will probably need also something like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/rope")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemode")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ropemacs")
```

(or whereever you have `pymacs.el`) so that emacs can find the lisp files. Also mentioned in the [pymacs documentation](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html#check-the-search-paths)

> 2.4 Install the Pymacs proper ... for the Emacs part ...
>
> This is usually done by hand now.
> First select some directory along the
> list kept in your Emacs *load-path*, for
> which you have write access, and copy
> file pymacs.el in that directory.

Comment: Alas, added the lines as recommended but no luck.

Comment: where do you have pymacs.el then?

Comment: Also check your load-path variable if it contains this directory (C-h v: load-path).

Comment: I don't think you need `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/rope")` and such, because rope, ropemode and ropemacs are python packages loaded via pymacs, so they are just needed to be in PYTHONPATH or pymacs-load-path. There are no Emacs lisp file in ropemacs directory. Please notice there is no `(require 'ropemacs)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If paths are missing then this will easily be spotted in the startup log or by getting a backtrace at emacs start. If in doubt M-x load-library is the way to go.

I too am getting company-ropemacs refusing to load with both emacs 23 and emacs 24 after latest Debian Testing updates which then means you can not save files because of rope save hooks. I would be interested to hear from anyone with it working. company-ropemacs and python in general with emacs has been a thorn for some time now. I intend to try and debug it some more later and will update this thread then.